# Error installing R package Rcpp

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am running R on Ubuntu 14.04. When trying to install package `dplyr` I get the below error.

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
sh: 1: -f: not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/dialog/r/r_libs/Rcpp’
```

I really cannot figure out what is meant by `sh: 1: -f: not found` 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not path related error? Can you compile codes CPP codes from terminal?

Comment: Yes. I can compile CPP code without any issue.

Comment: This problem was solved after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04